# AsyncTask onPostExecute - new intent error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have this code in my AsyncTask class:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        if (result == 1)
        {
            try {
                Global.mmOutStream.write(99);
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(TrashcanLocationActivity.this, TrashcanLocationActivity.class);     
            startActivity(intentTrashcanLocation);
        }

    }
```

This gives me error at the "`Intent`" line:

- line breakpoint:`TrashcanOnWayActiity$waitarrival [line:53] - onPostExecute(Integer)`
- No enclosing instance of the type `TrashcanLocationActivity` is accessible in scope

What I want to do is basically displaying the next page whenever I get certain input asynchronously. I couldn't solve this problem. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: you are starting same Activity in onPostExecute. if `TrashcanOnWayActiity` is current Activity then pass `TrashcanOnWayActiity.this` as first parameter to Intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same class

```
Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(TrashcanLocationActivity.this,
                                           TrashcanLocationActivity.class);     
startActivity(intentTrashcanLocation);
```

should be something along the lines

```
Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(TrashcanLocationActivity.this,
                                           TrashcandetailActivity.class);     
startActivity(intentTrashcanLocation);
```

Comment: Oh! So the first argument is the current activity and the second argument is the next activity?

Comment: Yes. It fixes the problem! Sorry about not researching enough before asking.. had too much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
           {
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               if (result == 1)
               {
                try {
                    Global.mmOutStream.write(99);
                    } catch (IOException e) { }

               Intent intent = new Intent(TrashcanLocationActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
               getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
              }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you are calling the same Activity again

```
 Intent intentTrashcanLocation = new Intent(TrashcanLocationActivity.this, TrashcanLocationActivity.class);     
            startActivity(intentTrashcanLocation);
```

replace `TrashcanLocationActivity.class` with the activity you want to call .class